# BST, successor, code issue

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I understand the general concept of successor in BST. Still there is something wrong with my code and I don't understand what's the problem.

The compilator runs the programm it starts and ends after a couple of seconds. I believe it's a 'segmentation fault' type of error (I'm using Windows and Dev C ++).

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
 };

 struct Node* head;

 struct Node* GetNewNode(int x){
    struct Node* newNode= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next =NULL;
 return newNode;
 }

 void InsertAtHead(int x){
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if(head==NULL){
        head=newNode;
        return;}
 newNode->next=head;
 head=newNode;
 }

 void Print(){
    struct Node* temp=head;
    printf("forward:");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
 }
 printf("\n");
 }

 void ReversePrint(struct Node* p){
    if(p==NULL){
        return;
    }
    ReversePrint(p->next);
    printf("%d",p->data);
 }

 int main(void){
    head=NULL;
    InsertAtHead(2); Print(); ReversePrint(2);
    InsertAtHead(4); Print(); ReversePrint(4);
    InsertAtHead(6); Print(); ReversePrint(6);

 }
```

Comment: what is this `ReversePrint(2)`?

Comment: If you have an error message post the __exact__ error message. What you 'believe' may not be accurate.

Comment: step through with the debugger

Comment: Why are you using a global variable for `head`?

Comment: The problem is that I get no error from my compilator. It runs the code and only then Windows writes that the program stopped working. That's all I get.

Comment: Replace `ReversePrint(number);` with `ReversePrint(head);`

Comment: It was "highly" recommendated during lecture on BST. I mean using head as a global variable.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys, especially thank You BLUEPIXY :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few errors to mention

1. You are always reassiging `head` in the `InsertAtHead()` function. You should instead keep a reference to the tail of the list, and update the next node on each call to `InsertAtHead()`.
2. You are passing an integer to `ReversePrint()` which is expecting a `struct Node` pointer, that is causing a segmentation fault.
3. You are never freeing the nodes. I didn't add a `FreeNodes()` function, it should be easy for you to implement.

This is a corrected version of your code, hope it helps you see your errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head;
struct Node* tail;

struct Node* GetNewNode(int x) {
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (newNode == NULL)
        return NULL;
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void InsertAtHead(int x) {
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = head;
        return;
    }
    if (tail != NULL)
        tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}

void Print(){
    struct Node* current = head;

    printf("forward:\n");
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("\t%d\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void ReversePrint(struct Node *node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    ReversePrint(node->next);
    printf("%d\n", node->data);
}

int main(void) {
    InsertAtHead(2);
    InsertAtHead(4);
    InsertAtHead(6);

    Print();
    ReversePrint(head);

    return 0;
}
```

you don't need explicitly initialize global variables to `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: @ninigi you can accept the answer if it worked for you.